# How to classify groups of order $6p$ where $p$ is a prime and of the form $p=6\ell+1$, especially $|G|=2022$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, semidirect-product

How to classify groups of order $6p$ where $p$ is a prime and of the form $p=6\ell+1$, especially $|G|=2022$?

I found some lists like [this one](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/%7Ezbimar/small_groups.pdf) and [this one](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/galpol), both show that $|G|=6p$ divides into two cases. I tried the standard ways like [the case of 2019](https://www.zhihu.com/question/353785684/answer/879553354) through semi-direct product, but the $2022$ cases seem more complicated.

Comment: 2022 is the current year.  Is this part of a challenge paper?

Comment: Examples of noncommutative groups of order $6p$: $S_3\times C_p$, $D_p\times C_3$, $H_p\times C_2$.
Here $H_p=\operatorname{gr}(a,b\mid a^3=1, d^p=1, aba^{-1}=b^t)$, where $t$ is the solution of the equation $t^2+t+1\equiv0\pmod{p}$. It can be shown that this equation has a solution if $p\equiv1\pmod6$.